# usage of the word "predictable"

Tags: word-meaning

> Robots are predictable in their work.

In this sentence , what does "predictable"  mean?
Does it mean, robots can predict what will happen
in their work or we can predict the conditions of robots while they are working?

Comment: We know you must have consulted your dictionary before asking this question. What did you not understand about the definition provided by that English language dictionary for the adjective _predictable_?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - It seems like the OP provided that information already. What did you not understand about "Does it mean, robots can predict what will happen in their work or we can predict the conditions of robots while they are working?"

Comment: @J.R. Any dictionary entry makes it clear that _predictable_  cannot be taken to mean _"able to predict"_. The OP's question makes it equally clear that _no_ dictionary was consulted; thus the five closevotes. I can understand that irony might be lost on the OP, but surely not on you!

Answer (score 3):

In your sentence, "predictable" means that the work the robot is doing is predictable. You know exactly what work the robot is going to do, presumably because you know how the robot was programmed and what its tasks are.

Robots can't really predict what will happen -- they don't have brains that could process that kind of information (not yet anyway). But if you wanted to say that a human can predict what will happen when he or she starts working, you might say something like:

> Humans are able to predict in their work.

Or:

> Robots will soon be predictive in their work.

Comment: -1 Your use of the adjective _predictable_ to explain the meaning of the adjective _predictable_ is less than informative.

Comment: I disagree. I think OP demonstrates he knows what predictable literally means, but just isn't sure how to interpret the sentence. If OP can use "predict" in guessing what "predictable" means in that sentence, surely he can understand this answer.

Comment: +1 for noticing the O.P. was not asking for the meaning of _predictable_, and, better yet, providing a good answer to the question.

Comment: Ha, point taken. Will try to fix up.

Comment: I am lazy and not sure how to fix up easily, so will take @cjl750 's point of view instead